# Configure wallet location in sqlnet.ora and listener.ora

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, ssl

I have a host containing multiple DBs and the connection to the DBs need to be SSL enabled. Since each DB has a unique wallet, I specify the wallet location in sqlnet.ora as:

```
WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=wallet_folder/$ORACLE_UNQNAME)))
```

This way the listener can use the correct wallet depending on the value of `ORACLE_UNQNAME` variable. But I have two issues with this method.

1. Since `ORACLE_UNQNAME` is a shell environment variable a client has no
   control over it.
2. Even when connecting from the same machine I have to bounce the listener after exporting `ORACLE_UNQNAME` value.

What is the solution for such a scenario ?

Comment: Each listener port has only one server certificate to present. The wallet location is interpreted at Listener start only. It’s not possible to have different wallets based on the request (I think it does not support different wallets per port or per SNI)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `$ORACLE_UNQNAME` to `$ORACLE_SID`. Assuming each Container DB has a unique `SID`, you can start the `CDB` with the right wallet as `ORACLE_SID` is required to start the database anyway.